# Django Admin: edit view shows no fields at all

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have defined a couple of models in a new `Django 1.8` app.

When I visit the Django Admin, the `list view` (the table where you see one row per each objects instance) works fine.

My surprise is that when I click on any `NSGateway` item and enter the `edit or create page`, there are no fields; just the `Save` buttons.

How can this be possible? All the `NSGateway` fields are shown as columns in the `list view`. But the `edit view` shows no fields!

These are the models:

```
from django.db import models


class Enterprise(models.Model):
    enterprise_id = models.CharField(max_length=40, primary_key=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    creationDate = models.DateTimeField()
    lastUpdatedDate = models.DateTimeField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description


class NSGateway(models.Model):
    nsgateway_id = models.CharField(max_length=40, primary_key=True)
    creationDate = models.DateTimeField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    lastUpdatedDate = models.DateTimeField()
    personality = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    # Each NSG belongs to 1 and only 1 Enterprise.
    # Thus, when we delete de Enterprise, we delete its NSG
    enterprise = models.ForeignKey(Enterprise, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description
```

This is how the corresponding `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from flexwan_import.models import Enterprise, NSGateway


class EnterpriseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('enterprise_id', 'name', 'description', 'creationDate',
                    'lastUpdatedDate')
    search_fields = ['enterprise_id', 'description']


class NSGatewayAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('nsgateway_id', 'name', 'description', 'creationDate',
                    'lastUpdatedDate')
    search_fields = ['nsgateway_id', 'description']


admin.site.register(Enterprise, EnterpriseAdmin)
admin.site.register(NSGateway, NSGatewayAdmin)
```

Comment: Inspect the div and check any css hidden mistakenly got applied, Another is ensure there is no any js which is hiding to the div of that class or id.

Comment: Interesting, never encounter an issue like this, if you try to put readonly_fields in the NSGatewayAdmin, can you see any read-only fields?

Comment: @MenglongLi thank you for your suggestion! I made the relationship field called "NSGateway.enterprises" as readonly and suddendly the edit view started showing all the expected fields. I really don't understand why, but it is certainly working. If you feel like writing a solution down below I will mark it as accepted.